# How to check if a function is callable with parameters?

Tags: php

I'm calling a function with call_user_func_array :

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'myFunction'), array('param1', 'param2', 'param3'));
```

Everything is ok unless I don't know how many parameters the function needs.
If the function needs 4 parameters it sends me an error, I'd like to test if I can call the function (with an array of parameters).
is_callable() doesn't allow parameters check.
Edit : If the call fails I need to call another function, that's why I need a check.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use reflection to get the number of parameters:

```
$refl = new ReflectionMethod(get_class($this), 'myFunction');
$numParams = $refl->getNumberOfParameters();
```

or

```
$numParams = $refl->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
```

See [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.reflection.php#language.oop5.reflection.reflectionmethod) for some more information

Comment: yes but the callback in the question is array($this, 'myFunction') , which implies the code is calling a method on itself

Answer (score 1):

One way getting around this is to call the function always with a *lot* of arguments. PHP is designed in such a way that you can pass as many extraneous arguments as you want, and the excess ones are just ignored by the function definition.

See manual entry for [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/func-get-args) to see an illustration about this.

*Edit:* As user crescentfresh pointed out, this doesn't work with built-in functions, only user defined functions. If you try to pass too many (or few) arguments into a built-in function, you'll get the following warning:

```
Warning: Wrong parameter count for strpos() in Command line code on line [...]
```

Comment: Ok, but if it fails I need to call another function. I'll edit my post.
Thanks!

Comment: It will fail for many built-in functions. Only userspace functions are the ones that php is forgiving of wrt superfluous args.